# git commit -i option in Android studio?

Tags: git, android-studio

The -i flag ignores certain files while committing. Is it possible to achieve this from inside Android Studio? Basically, I wish to ignore certain files just before commit as that file gets updated every second. Is it possible to achieve this in the android studio?

Comment: Does adding the file to your . gitignore file acheive the required results?

Comment: That's not what `-i` does: `git commit -i <paths>` means to *include extra files* in the commit, almost as if you had run `git add` on those paths. It does not cause any existing files to be ignored.

Comment: @torek That's not correct -i is for ignoring files.

Comment: @UtsavGupta: consult the official documentation: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html Note that `-i` and `--include` are two ways to spell the same option.